# Css overflow-y: hidden not working with inline elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been searching about this problem from last week...all I could found is this " overflow-x :hidden "

Here is my site : [seriesratings.com](http://seriesratings.com)

when I open it in my iphone, it shows me horizontal scrollbar.

I tried this already:

```
html,body{overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll}
```

someone has told me this "You have inline styles all over your html that will not be properly fixed by using css"

I can not change style now because site is fully developed.

does someone has any other way, like hide horizontal scrollbar with jquery or JS or any other code.

Comment: Please, could you show your code in jsfiddle? It would be hard to explain as there is no code at all

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy Sir, I have given the url of werbsite in the question...can you please remove the -1 from the question...It would be really helpful..Thank you : )

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (including all the relevant code), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Comment: @Lucky at the <div class="sg-site-header-1"></div> I found a H1 with an A tag in it, this thing causes the horizontal scroll-bar, why should you make a color #blank? This is not working, then make is display: invisible or something like that. Hopefully this will work for you!

Comment: @dutchsociety Thanks A Lot, you saved me, If you have time can you tell me how did you find out the solution to the problem, so I can do it by myself..

Comment: @dutchsociety thanks

Comment: @Lucky please make sure you vote my answer, well it is simple, I opened my element inspector in Google Chrome and deleting sections of the website. So on that moment I deleted the header and saw that there was the long sized H1.

Comment: @dutchsociety Thanks mate... but you have added the answer as a comment, I don't think there is any voteing system on comments. If you add it as an answer again. I would be more than happy to vote for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the sg-site-header-1 I found a H1 with an A tag in it, this thing causes the horizontal scroll-bar, why should you make a color #blank? This is not working, then make is display: invisible or something like that. Hopefully this will work for you!

```
@dutchsociety Thanks A Lot, you saved me, If you have time can you tell me how did you find out the solution to the problem, so I can do it by myself..
```

I opened my element inspector in Google Chrome and deleting sections of the website. So on that moment I deleted the header and saw that there was the long sized H1.

Comment: hey mate, I have accepted your answer.. to vote your answer, I'll need 15 reputation points. sorry I didn't know that..but thank you very much